# Add star to google maps account programatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a load of maps stars I want to transfer from one google account to another. I can export them as HTML and get a link to each one which looks something like this:

http://maps.google.com/?cid=1863378062783191712

I was then hoping to programmatically call a maps API to add these stars to another account. I can't seem to find anything in the Google Maps API that would allow this, however. It seems straightforward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to have been possible using [signed-in maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin), which is now deprecated. There is no support for this in the latest maps api.